# Python .__class__.__name__ works for one class and doesn't for another

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I'm sorry if I come across as incredibly stupid, I'm relatively new to python and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I have two classes, and I try to get the class names of both with

```
*class*.__class__.__name__
```

Now, as I said, this works for one class, but doesn't for another.

These are my classes:

```
class fb():
    val = 300
    mult = 2.0
    shsym = pygame.image.load('img/dummy2.png')
    value = 50
class a():
    occ = 0
    shsym = pygame.image.load('img/it/a/shsym.png')
    plsym = pygame.image.load('img/it/a/plsym.png')
    value = 100
    hesyms = [pygame.image.load('img/a/hesym0',pygame.image.load('img/dummy.png'))]
    coord = [(50, 300),(30, 435),(310, 350)]
```

The variables inside probably don't really matter but as I can't figure out the problem I just included the whole thing.

Then I define them

```
fob = fb()
ita = a()
```

Then I set a variable as one of the defined classes

```
itemselect = fob
```

And then, finally, I try to check the class' name and look if it begins with 'f' (to see if it is part of a group of items)

```
if not itemselect.__class__.__name__.startswith("f"):
```

And in that line I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programmieren\Cola Atsume\main.py", line 283, in <module>
     if not itemselect.__class__.__name__.startswith("f"):
AttributeError: class fa has no attribute '__class__'
```

When itemselect is ita everything works just fine, but with fob it doesn't.
I know I could do this differently, and my whole class system isn't really conventional and all but I don't really want to change it if I don't have to.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in either Python 2 or Python 3.  It's also obvious this isn't your actual code, since you're missing a `)` in the definition of `a.hesyms`.

Comment: Oh right, for formatting I tried around a little and didn't understand, but that should actually be the only difference.

Comment: In general, you should use `type(foo)` instead of `foo.__class__`, (unless you have a good reason to support old-style classes, which I would say you usually don't, since they don't even exist as of Python 3, and best practice in Python 2 code was to make your classes new-style ever since new-style classes existed).

Comment: I'd say in Python 3 you should only do `foo.__class__` when you want `type(foo)` to be able to lie to you about what class it is (this can be good if a library like `wrapt` is wrapping the object you are handling with a proxy object, in which case `foo.__class__` actually refers to the wrapped class rather than the wrapper class - but even then, most cases where you care about the wrapped class are situations where it is equally or more appropriate to either use `isinstance` for type checks or go through the instance instead of its class for attribute access.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** This is grindy Python 2 stuff. In Python 3, things are different because in Python 3, every class is ["new style"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) by default. New-Style classes themselves are also "simply" instances of their [meta-class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/1248008) (often this meta-class is `type`). This means that a class in Python 3 (and a Python 2 class inheriting from `object`) in fact has a `__class__` attribute (which carries its meta-class). Do not worry about meta-classes now.

When the error happens, `itemselect` is a **class**, not an instance, which is why it doesn’t have a `__class__` attribute.

You say that:

> Then I set a variable as one of the defined classes

Exactly, and **classes** do not have a `__class__` attribute. Only instances (also called objects) of classes have that attribute:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> hasattr(Foo, "__class__")
False
>>> f = Foo()
>>> hasattr(f, "__class__")
True
>>> f.__class__ is Foo
True
```

You need to distinguish classes and objects strongly, because in *most* cases it is the wrong thing to do to mix those.

---

Also, you really, really, really should not be doing this. You can easily convert this to an issubclass-based check.

Create an empty class called `f`:

```
class f:
    pass
```

Now base all your classes whose name starts with `f` on that class:

```
class fb(f):
    val = 300
    mult = 2.0
    shsym = pygame.image.load('img/dummy2.png')
    value = 50
```

And now, instead of doing the nasty `.startswith` check, use `issubclass`:

```
if issubclass(itemselect, f):
```

That is already a lot cleaner than checking for the first character in the name of a class.

---

Also, as a beginner nowadays, you really really really should not be using Python 2 and now you don’t have an excuse to use old-style classes either, because you know [new-style exists](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). It will make porting your code and *your mental model of how Python works* to Python 3 easier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm inexperienced, could you explain more?

Comment: You are not showing the code which produces the problem. You are not assigning ``ita`` or ``fob`` to ``itemselect`` when the error happens, because in that case it would work. You can confirm that by printing ``ita.__class__.__name__`` and ``fob.__class__.__name__``. You are, at some point, assigning ``fb`` to ``itemselect``. ``fb`` is a **class**, not an instance, and thus does not have the ``__class__`` attribute, because it is itself the class.

Comment: I am, I cut down a bit so the parts of the code shown aren't too confusing for people that don't know my code (which is everybody)

I assign it with a list called itemsl
    `itemsl = [fob,ita]
    
    itemselect = itemsl[0]`

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Sorry, I'm still practicing and classes are still pretty confusing for me. Also thanks for the quick answers, works now!